# Wrapping a synchronous NSURLConnection in a dispatch_async block vs Asynchronous Connection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

More generally, given a procedure that has both a synchronous and asynchronous version (like the `NSURLConnection`), is there any real difference between "wrapping" the synchronous version in a `dispatch_async` block like so:

```
dispatch_async(operationQueue, 
^{  [Class doSyncOperation];
});
```

and just calling the asynchronous version of the same operation?

Comment: I don't have a link or so at hand at the moment. But I think I remember that somewhere in the apple specs there is the statement that for performance reasons one should prefer the asynchronous versions rather the using the synchronous versions with GDC

Comment: I suspect that's the case too but I was just curious why it is, since I know basically nothing about how threading works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The asynchronous version of API's often offers additional information and possibly optimizations. The asynchronous version of `NSUrlConnection` for example has various callbacks for events such as receiving a response, receiving data, failures and success which allows for greater customization of your code. An example would being able to create a progress bar by use the async version of `NSURLConnection`. If you do not need an any additional information using `dispatch_async` will work, but you need to be sure that what you are calling uses thread confinement, and you may also lose any threading optimization provided by the library if any.